# PS Monitor Log File and update Variable with Latest Entry

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to monitor a logs file latest entry and then pass the output to a variable so I can then do other stuff, for this example I'm just going to pop a message in the console.

```
$fail = Get-Content 'C:\ProgramData\Software\APP.LOG' -Tail 0 -Wait | Select-String 'Error Alert Entry'
if ($fail -contains 'Error Alert Entry'){Write-Host "Warning Will Robinson!"}
```

I've tested the Get-Content command on its own and this does Tail the output of the log file without issue but when set as Variable I do not get anything.

I've also tested the latter portion and this works when I manually define the $fail Variable using something like this:

```
$fail = 'Error Alert Entry'
```

It appears that the Variable does not like being populated by actively Tailing a log file. I would appreciate if someone could provide some guidance on how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have to check your assumptions with PS. Try this:

```
$fail
```

and then this:

```
$fail.GetType()
```

and now this:

```
$fail[0].GetType()
```

What you thought was an array of `String` is actually an array of `MatchInfo` returned by `Select-String`. You should be able to get what you want by digging the `Value` out of the `MatchInfo` objects:

```
$fail.matches.value -contains 'Error Alert Entry'
```

Or you can dig the value out in the first line:

```
$fail = (Get-Content 'C:\ProgramData\Software\APP.LOG' -Tail 0 -Wait | Select-String 'Error Alert Entry').Matches.Value
```

I have to admit, `Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait` doesn't seem to work in my environment. That command seems to hang indefinitely despite making changes to the file.

/edit

Okay, I think I understand now. `Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait` never exits, so it never finishes piping its output to `Select-String` and never allows `$fail` to receive the data.

One solution might be to wrap your `Get-Content -Tail 0 -Wait` in a job and loop a `Receive-Job` call to execute your `Write-Host 'Warning Will Robinson!'`